# $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n!)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to study the character of this series 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log  n!)}$$

but I find always that the n-term is inferior to another n-term whose series diverges
while it should converge according to my book
Can someone help me to understan?

Comment: Note that $\ln{(n!)}=\sum_{k=2}^n\ln{(k)}\ge (n-1)\ln{(2)}$ for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use that, from Stirling's formula, you deduce instantly that $$\log(n!)\sim_\infty n\log n, \quad \text{so that }\quad\frac{1}{n(\log  n!)}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n^2\,\log  n},$$
which converges.

*Edit*: some details for the initial equivalence:

From Stirling's formula, you deduce that
$$\log(n!)=\tfrac12\log(2\pi n)+n\log n-n $$
The first and last terms are $o(n\log n)$, whence the equivalence with the middle term.

Comment: There is a factorial that shouldn't be there on the RHS

Comment: Oh! yes – copy-paste accident… Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: @Bernard $log (n!) \sim log (\frac{n^n}{{\sqrt {2\pi n} } *e^n})$ how can I ignore the factor $e^n $ and $\sqrt n$?

Comment: I've added some details. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Bernard yes, I got it! thanks for your help